# Ending script with if statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, while-loop

I'm very new to Python and want to know how to end a program with an if statement that prints a message, as this does not appear to be happening with my 'stand' variable when it is under < 5000.  The if statement bolded ** ** is the code I'm having trouble with and it still prints the message I want, however, the program does not stop with that message but continue going to the next code (countdown variable). Ignore 'countdown'.

Here is a part of my code.

```
   while stand <= 0 or mission > 10000: 
        try: 
            stand = int(input("Enter a VALID distance in metres: ")) 
        except ValueError: 
            print("Please enter a valid distance E.g 6000: ") 
    **if stand > 0 or stand < 5000: 
        print("ERROR, ERROR") 
        print("Launch cannot begin, the Mission Control and spectator stands are dangerously close at a distance of {}m.".format(mission)) 
        print("This launch site sucks! It must be demolished and rebuilt!") 
        print("Launch delayed.")**                   

    if stand >= 5000: 
        print("Fortunately the mission control and viewing stands are situated far enough.")              
    while countdown == 0 or countdown == "": 
        print("We need a person to countdown.")
        try:
            countdown = int(input("How many seconds would you like the countdown to be?: "))
        except ValueError:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to exit the loop.

```
if stand > 0 or stand < 5000:
    print("ERROR, ERROR") 
    print("Launch cannot begin, the Mission Control and spectator stands are dangerously close at a distance of {}m.".format(mission)) 
    break
```

Use `exit` to exit the program.

```
import sys
if stand > 0 or stand < 5000:
    print("ERROR, ERROR") 
    print("Launch cannot begin, the Mission Control and spectator stands are dangerously close at a distance of {}m.".format(mission)) 
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in function. A function you can return the different values. While Calling the function you can check what function is returning. 
You can use if condition like

```
def func1():
       while stand <= 0 or mission > 10000: 
            try: 
                stand = int(input("Enter a VALID distance in metres: ")) 
            except ValueError: 
                print("Please enter a valid distance E.g 6000: ") 
        **if stand > 0 or stand < 5000: 
            print("ERROR, ERROR") 
            print("Launch cannot begin, the Mission Control and spectator stands are dangerously close at a distance of {}m.".format(mission)) 
            print("This launch site sucks! It must be demolished and rebuilt!") 
            print("Launch delayed.")
            return 1**                   

        if stand >= 5000: 
            print("Fortunately the mission control and viewing stands are situated far enough.")              
        while countdown == 0 or countdown == "": 
            print("We need a person to countdown.")
            try:
                countdown = int(input("How many seconds would you like the countdown to be?: "))
            except ValueError:
r = func1() 
if r == 1:
  print 'Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use break statement inside if statement for termination. Instead of break we can write os.exit or sys.exit

os._exit calls the C function _exit() which does an immediate program termination. Note the statement "can never return".

sys.exit() is identical to raise SystemExit(). It raises a Python exception which may be caught by the caller.

```
import os

if stand > 0 or stand < 5000:
    print("ERROR, ERROR") 
    print("Launch cannot begin, the Mission Control and spectator stands are dangerously close at a distance of {}m.".format(mission)) 
    os.exit(0)
```